# How can I get value(10) from such array, $A= Array ( [Count(funded_by)] => 10)?

Tags: php, mysql

The code:

```
$A = Array ( [Count(funded_by)] => 10);
echo $A['Count(funded_by)'];
```

The errors:

> E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant funded_by - assumed 'funded_by' -- at line 3
>
> E_WARNING : type 2 -- Illegal offset type -- at line 3
>
> E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined index: Count(funded_by) -- at line 4

Comment: Since you are new to StackOverflow: be sure to accept an answer using the checkbox if an answer resolves your question, thank you.

Comment: Kindly Accept the answer that will help to another user !

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define a variable like that. You need single quotes not brackets.

```
<?php        

$a = array( 'Count(funded_by)' => 10);
echo $a['Count(funded_by)'];
```

Since you mentioned in another comment that this is the result from a query.  Usually you will do this in a query to make it more easily accessible:

```
SELECT COUNT(funded_by) AS total FROM your_table;
```

Then when you fetch the result, you can access it with `$result['total']`.  `total` becomes an alias of the value of `COUNT(funded_by)`